# string.split() in the lua string_ext module is not working

Tags: string, lua

I am trying to use the `split` method from the `string_ext` module in lua. But I am getting the following error:

```
E:\apps\Lua\5.1\lua\string_ext.lua:261: attempt to index global 'list' (a nil va
lue)
stack traceback:
        E:\apps\Lua\5.1\lua\string_ext.lua:261: in function 'split'
        stdin:1: in main chunk
        [C]: ?
```

My code is

```
require("string_ext")
print(string.split("An-example-string", "-"))
```

Thanks.

Comment: I would assume that the module requires another module called `list`. But I don't know `string_ext` so I can only guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for the response. I found that the `split` method in the `string_ext` requires the modules `list` and `strbuf`. Importing them solves the problem. But this seems stupid. Shouldn't a library function import the modules that it uses to make it self contained rather than making the user of the library import the necessary modules that the library uses?

Answer (score 2):

From the `string_ext` code on [code.google.com](http://code.google.com/p/luapack/source/browse/trunk/Win32/lua/string_ext.lua?r=19&spec=svn19#265), the function `split` goes like this:

```
function split (sep, s)
  local pairs = list.concat ({0}, list.flatten (finds (s, sep)), {0})
  local l = {}
  for i = 1, #pairs, 2 do
    table.insert (l, sub (s, pairs[i] + 1, pairs[i + 1] - 1))
  end
  return l
end
```

And the `list` module they are using is also available [here](http://code.google.com/p/luapack/source/browse/trunk/Win32/lua/list.lua?r=19).